# Typo3 test mail not working via install tool

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm having an issue with sending an email in typo3, i.e I haven’t received emails if I used to send a test mail via install tool or via Mail API function. But if I add a direct PHP mail function to the main folder of the server I have received the emails. could anybody please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into your configuration in install tool.
There you have an configuration `[MAIL][transport]`, with multiple options:

> **mail**
>       Sends messages by delegating to PHP's internal mail() function. No further settings required. This is the most unreliable option. If you are serious about sending mails, consider using "smtp" or "sendmail".
>   **smtp**
>       Sends messages over the (standardized) Simple Message Transfer Protocol. It can deal with encryption and authentication. Most flexible option, requires a mail server and configurations in transport_smtp_* settings below. Works the same on Windows, Unix and MacOS.
>   **sendmail**
>       Sends messages by communicating with a locally installed MTA - such as sendmail. See setting transport_sendmail_command bellow.
>   **mbox**
>       This doesn't send any mail out, but instead will write every outgoing mail to a file adhering to the RFC 4155 mbox format, which is a simple text file where the mails are concatenated. Useful for debugging the mail sending process and on development machines which cannot send mails to the outside. Configure the file to write to in the 'transport_mbox_file' setting below
>   **<classname>**
>       Custom class which implements Swift_Transport. The constructor receives all settings from the MAIL section to make it possible to add custom settings.

There are further configuration for these options (smtp, sendmail, mbox)
And don't forget that the mail service might reject mails which do not match some requirements.